# Exercise 7,section 1, chapter 6 of Conway's *A course in Functional Analysis*.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The following problem is a Exercise 7,section 1, chapter 6 of Conway's *A course in Functional Analysis*

Let $A\in {\cal B}(c_0)$ (${\cal B}(c_0)$ is linear bounded operators on $c_0$) and for $n\geq 1$, define $e_n \in c_0$ by $e_n(m)=\delta_{mn}$. Put $\alpha_{mn}=(Ae_n)(m)$ for $n,m\geq 1$. I would like to $(a): M = \sup_m\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\alpha_{mn}|< \infty.$ and $(b): \text{for every}\quad n, \alpha_{mn}\to  0 \quad \text{as}\quad m\to\infty.$

**My attempt:** I have proved $(a)$

I do not quite understand how to prove $(b)$

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: $Ae_n \in c_0$ which already implies that $Ae_n(m) \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: Rhys Steele thank I edited it